# Is my conditional PDF calculation correct?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, solution-verification

Modify problem 4 p.98/142 from this [PDF](http://cst.uwaterloo.ca/316/Notes/316-notes.pdf):

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[image: img]

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}  cxy,&  \mbox{if } 0\leq x\leq y\leq 1,\\ 0,&  \mbox{otherwise,}\end{cases}$

If we know $Y = 0.5$, is my conditional calculation of $f_{X|Y}(x\, |\, 0.5)$ below correct?

The joint PDF now becomes:
$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = cxy, \textrm{for}~0 \leq x \leq y \leq 0.5 $

$\displaystyle \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y) = c\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} xy\,dy\,dx = c\int\limits_{0}^{0.5}\int\limits_{x}^{0.5} xy\,dy\,dx = c\int\limits_{0}^{0.5} x\frac{y^2}{2}\Big |_{x}^{0.5}\,dx = \frac{c}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{0.5} x\cdot y^2\Big |_{x}^{0.5}\,dx$

$\displaystyle = \frac{c}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{0.5} x\cdot \left(\frac{1}{4} - x^2\right)\,dx = \frac{c}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{0.5} \left(\frac{x}{4} - x^3\right)\,dx = \frac{c}{2}\left(\frac{x^2}{8} - \frac{x^4}{4}\right)\Bigg |_{0}^{0.5} = \frac{c}{2}\left(\frac{1}{32} - \frac{1}{64}\right) = \frac{c}{128} = 1$

Thus, $c = 128$.

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 128\cdot xy, \textrm{for}~0 \leq x \leq y \leq 0.5 $

$\displaystyle f_{Y}(y) = 128\cdot \int\limits_{0}^{0.5}xy\,dx = 128y\cdot \int\limits_{0}^{0.5}x\,dx = 128y\cdot \frac{x^2}{2}\Bigg |_{0}^{0.5} = 64y\cdot x^2\Bigg |_{0}^{0.5} = 16y$

Therefore:

$\displaystyle f_{X|Y}(x\mid Y = 0.5) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,0.5)}{f_{Y}(y)} = \frac{128xy}{16y} = 8x $

Did I get it right?

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

From Maxim's suggestion:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = cxy, \textrm{for}~0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1 $

$\displaystyle \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y) = c\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} xy\,dy\,dx = c\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{x}^{1} xy\,dy\,dx = c\int\limits_{0}^{1} x\frac{y^2}{2}\Big |_{x}^{1}\,dx = \frac{c}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{1} x\cdot y^2\Big |_{x}^{1}\,dx$

$\displaystyle = \frac{c}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{1} x\cdot \left(1 - x^2\right)\,dx = \frac{c}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{1} \left(x - x^3\right)\,dx = \frac{c}{2}\left(\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{4}\right)\Bigg |_{0}^{1} = \frac{c}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}\right) = \frac{c}{8} = 1$

Thus, $c = 8$.

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 8\cdot xy, \textrm{for}~0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1 $

$\displaystyle f_{Y}(y) = 8\cdot \int\limits_{0}^{y}xy\,dx = 8y\cdot \int\limits_{0}^{y}x\,dx = 8y\cdot \frac{x^2}{2}\Bigg |_{0}^{y} = 4y\cdot x^2\Bigg |_{0}^{y} = 4y^3,~y\in [0,1]$

Therefore:

$\displaystyle f_{X|Y}(x\mid Y = 0.5) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,0.5)}{f_{Y}(y)} = \frac{8xy}{4y^3} = \frac{2x}{y^2}  = \frac{2x}{0.5^2}  = 8x,~x\in [0,0.5]$

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Maxim's beautiful method:

$\displaystyle f_{X \mid Y = y}(x \mid Y = y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}  = \frac {cxy \, [0 \leq x \leq y]} {\int_0^y cxy \, dx} = \frac {cxy \, [0 \leq x \leq y]} {cy\int_0^y x \, dx} = \frac {cxy\, [0 \leq x \leq y]} {cy\frac{x^2}{2}\big|_0^y}$

$\displaystyle = \frac {cxy}{cy\frac{y^2}{2}}~[0 \leq x \leq y] = \frac {2 x} {y^2}~[0 \leq x \leq y]$

Thus,
$\displaystyle f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) = \frac {2 x} {y^2},~\textrm{for}~0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1$

Comment: That's the right answer but you went about it the long way.  First you found the joint distribution of $x$ and $y$ given that $y<1/2$ and then applied the conditional density formula at the end.  Why not just find $c$ in the initial joint density and then apply the conditional density formula?  (You also used the symbols $c$ and $f_{X,Y}$ for both the conditional and unconditional densities.)

Comment: Whatever value $Y$ takes, it doesn't change the constant $c$ in the definition of $f_{X, Y}$ (and $c \neq 128$). Write the conditional pdf formula for symbolic $y$ and $c$ with the assumption $0 < y < 1$. You should get
$$f_{X \mid Y = y}(x) =
\frac {c x y \, [0 < x < y]} {\int_0^y c x y \, dx} =
\frac {2 x} {y^2} [0 < x < y].$$

Comment: @Maxim, is the amended answer correct?

Comment: Correct. To be more rigorous, you can write the pdfs as $f_Y(y) = 4 y^3 \hspace {1.5px} [0 < y < 1]$ and
$$f_{X \mid Y = 1/2}(x) = 8 x \hspace {1.5px} [0 < x < 1/2]$$
(clearly it can't be just $8 x$ for any value of $x$).

Comment: Edited as suggested.